# What exactly is order of magnitude?

Tags: definition, order-of-magnitude

I am little bit confused with what [order of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) is. In my book it says, when we write approximate values of quantities in powers of ten i.e $10^b$, then $10^b$ is the order of magnitude. But later it says that the exponent of the 10 i.e b, is the order of magnitude. I searched many websites some of them say $10^b$ is the order of magnitude and some of them say $b$ is the order of magnitude. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Exactly? The entire point of the concept is that it's inexact ツ

Answer (score 6):

It's both. If you asked me to give the order of magnitude of some quantity that we're talking about, perhaps to get an idea of the physical scales involved, I would use $10^b$. So if I was talking about, say, galaxies, and you asked me about the typical order of magnitude of the masses, I would say "of the order of $10^{12} M_{\odot}$".  But if one galaxy is 100 times more massive than the other, I would say that the masses are two orders of magnitude apart.

Comment: When you're asked about the typical order of magnitude of galaxies and you say "of the order of $10^{12} M_{\odot}$", you are saying the desired order of magnitude is the same as the order of magnitude of the quantity $10^{12}$, which is $12$. The order of magnitude is the exponent.

Comment: -Javier, Now I got it, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @electronpusher I disagree. If someone asks me for the order of magnitude and I'm being really brief, I'm answering $10^{12}$, but never 12.

Comment: Well, that doesn't demonstrate what it is, just what your impression of it is. If they asked me, I'd say 12 (and that doesn't make it right either). There's several answers here and a curious lack of citations of authoritative sources on terminology.

Comment: @Javier If you have a $100 investment that increases in value to $1000, how many orders of magnitude has it increased?

Comment: @electronpusher AFAIK there is no authoritative source on terminology of this kind, because it's not a precise mathematical definition. The only source is how people use the words, and I'm giving my personal impression. And I'd answer "one" to your question, but I'd answer "a thousand dollars" if you asked me for the order of magnitude of my earnings. Like I said in my answer, I think the meaning of the phrase can vary.

Comment: @Javier What would you say the order of magnitude of a thousand is?

Comment: @electronpusher A thousand. Yes, I'm serious. I wouldn't say "three".

Answer (score 2):

Order of magnitude is used for describing roughly how big something is. Sort of like distinguishing between really big and ginormous. For example, the galaxy is much bigger than the solar system, but it isn't obvious how much bigger.

The radius of the solar system is $4.5 \cdot 10^9$ km. The radius of the galaxy is $4.7 \cdot 10^{17}$ km.

Which means the galaxy is about $10^8$ times bigger, or 8 orders of magnitude bigger. The difference between $4.5$ and $4.7$ doesn't really matter when talking about approximate numbers like this.

It is also useful when talking about tiny and microscopic numbers. A typical diameter of an atom is 1 Angstrom or $10^{-10}$ m. The diameter of a nucleus is $4$ to $15$ femtometers, or $4$ to $15 \cdot 10^{-15}$ m. The nucleus is about $10^4$ times smaller, or $4$ orders of magnitude smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If we write $N=a×10^b$, $b$ is the order of magnitude. For example, the number 1 has 0 orders of magnitude. However, this concept of orders of magnitude is more useful while comparing numbers. For example, to compare $3$ and $1000$ we could say that $1000$ is $997$ more than $3$, but sometimes, it’s more convenient to say that $1000$ is $3$ orders of magnitude greater than $3$.

Comment: I would also mention that $1\leq a < 10$ in your notation.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Indeed, a factor of ~1000 is 3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: So if the exponent of 10 is the order of magnitude, then what should i take when they say 10^b is the order of magnitude ?

Comment: As far as I know, 10^b is not the “order of magnitude”. It’s b. When they say 10^b is the order of magnitude, they’re wrong (?). Where exactly did you come across 10^b being the order of magnitude?

Comment: @Heisenberg, my two cents: I've seen people refer to $10^b$ as "the magnitude" of a number in standard form. So maybe the nuance here is "order of magnitude" vs simply "magnitude".

Comment: Heisenberg, I came across that while studying Physics in HC Verma.

Comment: Thank you all for looking out for me.

Comment: My doubt got cleared

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer you’re probably right. I can see how the similarities between the terms “magnitude” and “order of magnitude” could create confus.

Comment: could create confusion*.